# Data Table using directive in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

here i am trying to create my own directive. I wanted to create data table. i don't know is i am doing anything wrong.please help me to find
[js-fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ajithravindran/36ed11ay/)
code ;

```
<div ng-app='test'>
 <div ng-controller='ctrl'>
  {{name}}
  <div ibatable tb-head='header' model='model' columns='columns' ></div>
</div>
 </div>

(function(){
  var app=angular.module('test',[]);
 app.controller('ctrl',function($scope){
$scope.name='ajith';
$scope.header=['Name','Class'];
$scope.columns=['m.name','m.class'];
$scope.model=[{name:'ajith',class:'12'},{name:'ajith1',class:'122'}];
});
app.directive('ibatable',function(){
 return{
restrict:'A',
scope:{tbHead:'=',model:'=',columns:'='},
template:"<table><tr ><th ng-repeat='h in tbHead'>{{h}}</th></tr><tr ng-      repeat='m in model'><td ng-repeat='c in columns'>{{m.+{{c}}}}</td></tr></table>"
  //here i wnt to call m.name and m.class dynamically
};
});
})();
```

Comment: help me please... even is this was a stupid question

Comment: dont know what you re trying to do but in the fiddle replace {} with [] in $scope.header

Comment: Vanojx , sorry the correct fiddle is https://jsfiddle.net/ajithravindran/36ed11ay/

Comment: iam trying to repeat td

Comment: I know it is not exactly what u are looking for , but u can do like this :) https://jsfiddle.net/36ed11ay/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your template by below:

```
template: "<table><tr><th ng-repeat='h in tbHead'>{{h}}</th></tr><tr ng-repeat='m in model'><td ng-repeat='c in m'>{{c}}</td></tr> </table>"
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're making the template a bit more complicated than it needs to be.  Here's what I did:

```
(function(){
    angular.module('test',[])
    .controller('ctrl',function($scope){
        $scope.name='ajith';
        $scope.header=['Class','Name'];
        $scope.model=[{name:'ajith',class:'12'},{name:'ajith1',class:'122'}];
    })
    .directive('ibatable',function(){
        return{
            restrict:'A',
            scope: {
        tbHead:'=',
        model:'=',
        columns:'='
       },
            template:"<table><tr><th ng-repeat='h in tbHead'>{{h}}</th></tr><tr ng-repeat='m in model'><td ng-repeat='(key, value) in m'>{{m[key]}}</td></tr></table>"
        };
    });
})();
```

More specifically, the template can be rewritten as:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th ng-repeat='h in tbHead'>{{h}}</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat='m in model'>
        <td ng-repeat='(key, value) in m'>{{m[key]}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Rather than try to reference values in your model by building up the name, you can just iterate over the model itself by using the (key, value) notation with ngRepeat. Check out the [Iterating over object properties](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) section of the official docs for more info.